# get the data using contains() in linq to sql query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm trying to get the list of records from a crm entity using c#.
Trying to get the records with IDs present in another list.

Here is the query:

```
 private static List<plus_visit> GetVisits(IOrganizationService service, List<Guid> customVendorIDs = null)
  {  
        var visits = new List<plus_visit>();
        using (var crm = new CrmServiceContext(service))
        {
            try
            {
               visits = crm.plus_visitSet.Where(a => customVendorIDs.Contains(a.ow_Vendor.Id)).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utility.LogError(ex);
            }
            return visits;
        }
```

I'm getting the error, "Invalid where condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."

It works when I change it to .tolist() like below, but it is taking a lot of time to convert first to list and then querying on it.

```
visits = crm.plus_visitSet.tolist().Where(a => customVendorIDs.Contains(a.ow_Vendor.Id)).ToList();
```

plus_visit is generated using XRMToolbox early bound generator. It looks as:

```
public System.Linq.IQueryable<CrmEarlyBound.plus_visit> plus_visitSet
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
        get
        {
            return this.CreateQuery<CrmEarlyBound.plus_visit>();
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you not use QueryExpression. It shall be easy to fetch data from CRM and should be easily readable.Try this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/use-filterexpression-class)

Comment: Yes, I had to find an alternate solution, implemented a LINQ to SQL query instead of contains.

Comment: If you want I can provide your with psuedo or Query Expression code, if you let me know your criteria.

Comment: In addition I belive Contains will not work if you want to filte with Guid, Try with In or equals operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/org-service/use-linq-construct-query#linq-limitations) you can find list of LINQ limitations. Your query falles under 'The left side of the clause must be an attribute' rule...

If `customVendorIDs` are also retrieved with LINQ query, you can work around this limitation by joining tables with vendor filter to get only desired `plus_visitSet` records.

Please note that with `crm.plus_visitSet. ** tolist() ** ...` query you are retreiving all `plus_visit` records from database and then filtering this out. It could be significant hit on performance....